# How can I refactor this method? (spring + java8)

Tags: spring, java-8

I am trying to refactor the Java class below. I have a method that saves a POJO (entity) depending on which instance it belongs to.

The code below shows only 3 services but there is 13 service in total.
Each service is calling a separate *RepositoryImpl.
For instance,  the ActiviteService is an interface and the activiteService.create(activity) will call the implementation of that interface.

```
@Autowired
private ActiviteService       activiteService;
@Autowired
private AdresseMsSanteService    adresseMsSanteService;
@Autowired
private AttributionParticuliereService     attributionParticuliereService;



private boolean sauvegarder(Object object, Long idIdPlay, String game,
    Integer gameIndex) {


    boolean isSaved = false;

    if (idIdPlay == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("IdPlay id is null");
    }

    if (object instanceof Activite) {
        Activite activite = (Activite) object;
        activite.setIdIdPlay(idIdPlay);
        if (this.isGameOn(activite, game, gameIndex)) {
            activiteService.create(activite);
            isSaved = true;
        }
    } else if (object instanceof AdresseMsSante) {
        AdresseMsSante adresseMsSante = (AdresseMsSante) object;
        adresseMsSante.setIdIdPlay(idIdPlay);
        if (this.isGameOn(adresseMsSante, game, gameIndex)) {
            adresseMsSanteService.create(adresseMsSante);
            isSaved = true;
        }
    } else if (object instanceof AttributionParticuliere) {
        AttributionParticuliere attributionParticuliere = (AttributionParticuliere) object;
        attributionParticuliere.setIdIdPlay(idIdPlay);
        if (this.isGameOn(attributionParticuliere, game, gameIndex)) {
            attributionParticuliereService.create(attributionParticuliere);
            isSaved = true;
        }
    } else if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would create an interface representing your Game Entity. For instance:

```
public interface GameEntity {
    void setIdIdPlay(Long idIdPlay);
}
```

After that, you create the classes that implement the GameEntity interface:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class AdresseMsSante implements GameEntity {
    @Id
    Long idIdPlay;

    public void setIdIdPlay(Long idIdPlay) {
        this.idIdPlay = idIdPlay;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table
public class Activite implements GameEntity {
    @Id
    Long idIdPlay;

    public void setIdIdPlay(Long idIdPlay) {
        this.idIdPlay = idIdPlay;
    }
}
```

Then, create your generic repository which will save every Game Entity.

```
@Repository
public class Repo {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void save(GameEntity obj) {
        entityManager.merge(obj);
    }
}
```

Finally, your method will be like that:

```
 @Autowired
    Repo repo;

 private boolean sauvegarder(Object object, Long idIdPlay, String game,
                                Integer gameIndex) {
        boolean isSaved = false;
        if (idIdPlay == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("IdPlay id is null");
        }
        GameEntity gameEntity = (GameEntity) object;
        gameEntity.setIdIdPlay(idIdPlay);
        if(this.isGameOn(gameEntity, game, gameIndex)) {
            repo.save(gameEntity);
            isSaved = true;
        }
        return isSaved;
    }


    boolean isGameOn(GameEntity gameEntity,  String game, Integer gameIndex) {
        // do something
        return true;
    }
```